# How do I transfer a MySQL Database without full permissions?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to transfer a Database that is on my localhost to another server via PHPMyAdmin. The database is a custom WordPress one.

The user priveleges the server owner has given me doesn't allow me to create a new database, however they have created an empty database to import mine into.

Any ideas how to do this in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: PHPmyadmin does have the ability to create a database snapshot or "dump". You shouldn't need special privileges to back it up, and you should be able to restore it to any database you have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple 2 step process of an export & import.

### Step 1

Within your localhost's PHPMyAdmin, open the database that needs to be transferred. This is usually prefixed with `wp_` unless you've specified otherwise.

Within that, you should have tabs that look something similar to below

```
Structure | SQL | Search | Query | Export | Import |Operations
```

If you click on the export. Select all of the tables and chose for it to be exported into SQL then hit the download/go button

### Step 2

Open up the other server's PHPMyAdmin, go to the database that they have given to you and then import the file.

The page should just have an upload and go feature.

### Within Wordpress

Alternatively, you could install WordPress first and then transfer the data using WordPress's built in export/import functionality.